# Событие на клик для другого элемента

Tags: jquery, click, alert

подскажите пожалуйста как написать событие на клик для другого элемента. Например на каждую цифру есть событие на клик с alert её значения. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на point-1 например, происходило событие клика на соответствующую цифру ?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">point-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">point-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">point-3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">point-4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="bot-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: уточните пожалуйста вопрос. Непонятно, что нужно сделать

Comment: Извиняюсь, даже не заметил что не отправилось сообщение. Нежно чтобы при клике на point-1 обрабатывалось происходил так же клик на "1" в bot-menu. Ну и по аналогии с point-2. Т.е. нужно само событие, которое этот клик делает при определенных условиях

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С `data` атрибутами будет работать быстрее

```js
$( ".bot-menu a" ).on("click", function() {
  console.log("bot-menu: ", $(this).text());
});

$( ".top-menu a" ).on("click", function() {
  console.log("top-menu: ", $(this).text());
  let index = $(this).text().split('-')[1];
  $('.bot-menu a[data-id="' + index + '"]').trigger( "click" );
  //$('.bot-menu:contains(index)');
  //console.log($('.bot-menu a[data-id="' + index + '"]'));
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">point-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">point-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">point-3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">point-4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="bot-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="4">4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

или без `data` атрибутов  будет работать немного медленнее

```js
$( ".bot-menu a" ).on("click", function() {
  console.log("bot-menu: ", $(this).text());
});

$( ".top-menu a" ).on("click", function() {
  console.log("top-menu: ", $(this).text());
  let index = $(this).text().split('-')[1];
  $('.bot-menu a:contains(' + index + ')').trigger( "click" );
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">point-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">point-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">point-3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">point-4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="bot-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Достаточно было бы использовать просто индекс элемента, по которому кликнули, без определения номера из текста)

Comment: @DaemonHK, Это не совсем надежно, использовать индекс как ключ не очень хорошая практика. Если изменится, то код может начать неправильно работать. А так спасибо за замечание))

Comment: Это понятно) просто я написал облегченный вариант именно для данной структуры))

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов, вам нужно установить data атрибуты на элементы в верхнем и нижнем контейнере, и считывать их при клике в верхнем контейнере, и потом в замыкание события "click" пройтись по элементам из bot-menu и найти элемент, у которого такой же data атрибут и выполнить по нему программный клик.